# How to define an object with a veriable name in JSON Schema?

Tags: json, enums, jsonschema

I want to create a JSON schema for this JSON "pseudo-code" example:

```
{
    "xyz": {
        "$something": {
            "property_a": "...",
            "property_b": "...",
            "property_c": "..."
        }
    }
}
```

`$something` can be one of the following strings: `foo`, `bar`, or `buz`. My current schema looks like this:

```
{
  "xyz": {
    "id": "xyz",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "foo": {
        "id": "foo",
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "required": ["property_a"],
        "properties": {
          "property_a": {
            "id": "property_a",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "property_b": {
            "id": "property_b",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "property_c": {
            "id": "property_a",
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "bar": {
        ... copy&paste foo
      },
      "buz": {
        ... copy&paste foo
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's working, but it's a lot duplicated code. So I'm looking for a more elegant way for implementing it.

**How to define a list of values (lie `enum`) allowed as name for a property in JSON Schema?**

Comment: Have you looked at [oneOf](https://ajv.js.org/keywords.html#oneof) along with references?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! `oneOf`, `anyOf` etc. are applicable to the "_value of the keyword_". What I'm trying to achieve, is to make the _key_ variable.

Comment: This looks like jsonapi. There's a good example of what you might be trying to do here: https://github.com/eneuhauser/json-api/blob/schema/schema. I use that schema to validate all my resources and it uses references to check the shape of the response. It looks like it uses pattern properties to define variable values, in addition to the one of for known values

Comment: Have you looked at `patternProperties`? It's not an enum, but you can make a list in a regex. Or is there something more you want? =]

Comment: @Relequestual Yes, it's actually exactly, what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`patternProperties` works like properties, except the keys of the object are regular expressions.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.5.5

An example from the [Understanding JSON Schema site](http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#pattern-properties)

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "patternProperties": {
    "^S_": { "type": "string" },
    "^I_": { "type": "integer" }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

> In this example, any additional properties whose names start with the
> prefix S_ must be strings, and any with the prefix I_ must be
> integers. Any properties explicitly defined in the properties keyword
> are also accepted, and any additional properties that do not match
> either regular expression are forbidden.